# Setting focus manually with Sony Camera API

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I'm making a follow focus app for Sony cameras. My app needs to be able to set focus marks and recall them. There are a lot of functions for doing AF on the Sony Camera API, but I'd like to be able to set focus manually to a given absolute value. Is there a way to accomplish this with the Sony Camera API?

If not, am I able to make a feature request for the next version?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is no way to manually set the focus to a value in the API.  But I will let the team know about the feature request.

Comment: well that was a Long time ago .. still no change :/